# is there any way to change access of file(or folder) while uploading file to google drive through api

Tags: google-drive-api

I am able to upload images using uploadtype=multipart but I want to change access level from private(which I assume is default while uploading) to public sharing while uploading images itself.I came across this links https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert and https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-sharing#retrieving_adding_and_manipulating_permissions but they allow you to change permission after you get fileId(I assume after uploading file I can get that)so is there any way I can change access while uploading file itself.Also is there any way to do that for folders.Also I would be uploading images only not anything else

Comment: The only multipart upload Files.insert() supports is metadata. I don't think you can modify permission with file upload with one query.